# NodeJS - Stream in what the server is doing

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream, websocket

I'm creating a simple webpage with NodeJS that'll upload a picture, resize it, pull some information from the web about the picture, and then save to the database. Easy stuff, all of it done server side. Though I'm trying to write an new feature that I'm a bit lost on how to go about. What I'd like to do is 'print' to the client when it's started each step of the process I mentioned about.

Imagine it like a white box, and every time something happens on the server, a new line is written says what for the client to read. How would I go about this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: maybe use `res.send`?

Answer (score 1):

Use socket.io or some other websocket library. When the page loads, open a connection (in the browser's javascript). On the server, as events happen, send them as socket.io messages. In the browser, as events arrive, set them into a "status" element or append them to a list or whatever. You should be able to find lots of examples of chat servers out there and just convert chat messages to progress updates and there you have your architecture.

http://howtonode.org/websockets-socketio

Try something, then post a code snippet.